# Get System.Drawing.Font width?

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, system.drawing

I'm using .Net tools to do some 2D drawing. `System.Drawing.Font` uses a `GetHeight()` that returns the height in pixels. I'm missing a `GetWidth()` to retrieve the width! What should I use?

Comment: Perhaps [Graphics.MeasureString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) might help?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4219798/1577396) might be helpful too.

Comment: Height actually gives you the linespacing, not the font height

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use  **[Graphics.MeasureString Method (String, Font)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)**:

Eg.

```
   // Set up string. string measureString = "Measure String";
    Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
    // Measure string.
    SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));
    stringSize = gfx.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);
    // This will give you string width, from which you can calculate further 
    double width = stringSize.Width
```

Answer (score 4):

What width? `GetHeight` returns the distance between the baselines of two lines of text, which is a property of the font itself. But the width depends on what you're going to write.

If you know what it is you want to write, try the [`Graphics.MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h597fsh.aspx) methods.