# How to get string's width

Tags: c#-4.0, dll

**Edit**

Graphics is from a Pdf in memory, but I am not sure how to use that with Graphics class...
Not sure what's e in this answer [Get System.Drawing.Font width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269145/get-system-drawing-font-width)

---

- It's a library project I am working on - not Windows Forms.

---

**First Question**

Trying to get string's width using this method,

```
    public static void GetStringWidth(string measureString)
    {
        Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
        SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
        stringSize = Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);
        double width = stringSize.Width;

        Console.WriteLine(width);
    }
```

**But getting error,**

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(string, System.Drawing.Font)'

[image]

Comment: You're calling an instance method as though it were static.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but i don't know what it means :/

Comment: You need to go learn the difference between static class methods and members, and their instance counterparts. The former are essentially "global", they exist once. The latter exist separately for every instance of that class.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Just did, Graphics is not a static class, so I need to create an object of it, but now the problem is I am trying to get width of a string which I am yet to add to a pdf "Memory Stream"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MeasureString is not a static method. You will need to use a Graphics instance to access it.

For example:

```
private void MeasureString(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    string measureString = "Measure String";
    Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
    SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
    stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);
}
```

If you are referencing System.Windows.Forms use the TextRenderer class instead, this will relieve you of  having a Graphics object.

```
private void MeasureText()
{
    String text1 = "Some Text";
    Font arialBold = new Font("Arial", 16);
    Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text1, arialBold);
}
```

UPDATE:

You can use a fake image to measure a string using Graphics as we cannot use CreateGraphics in a class library:

```
private void MeasureString()
{
    string measureString = "Measure String";
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 16);
    Image fakeImage = new Bitmap(1,1); 
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(fakeImage);
    SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(measureString, font);
}
```

Comment: ++1 @Red Serpent, Sorry I forgot to mention - I need it in a library class

Comment: @CustomizedName Updated answer for class libraries