# Limit text to width of TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-store-apps, text-width

I'm using a `TextBox` to create an editable title on something that looks like a post-it note. I changed to a `TextBox` from a `RichEditBox` to see if that could solve my problem, which it didn't, so I'm willing to change back if that helps.

My problem is that I don't want the user to be able to enter more characters than fit in the set width of the `TextBox`, because I want the whole title to be visible. Setting a fixed limit to the amount of characters that can be entered doesn't really work since for example 10 large M's would fill the width of my `TextBox`, but other characters will only fill half of it. So I would like to compare the width of the text to the width of the `TextBox`, so I can restrict input beyond that point.

Edit: I'm using the Segoe UI font, and I don't really consider changing the font to one with characters of equal width as a solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219798/determine-how-wide-a-rendered-character-is-in-net or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721168/how-to-determine-the-size-of-a-string-given-a-font which may help

Comment: I've tried looking into the properties of the TextBox and RichEditBox and tried basically anything that could relate to this. I tried disabling wordwrap, the built-in scroll of RichEditBox and the AcceptsReturn property. I tried the DataWriter's MeasureString method, which turned out to measure the amount of characters. Couldn't find any other way of measuring the width of the string.

Comment: What about basing it off the width of the text box itself?

Comment: Don't have access to neither Graphics nor TextRenderer nor FormattedText in a Windows Store App. So the links don't really help.

Comment: The TextBox doesn't scale, there's like a space inside it that contains the text, so it can't extend the width of the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Set the TextBox Font to a Courier Font, then all characters are equal width and calculating max becomes trivial.

Comment: Not really the perfect solution since I wanted the segoe font that is so iconic for the windows store apps. But still a nice backup solution!

Comment: Found the Segoe UI Mono font, which has the same property as the Courier Font. Close to perfect at least. I still find it strange that there is no better solution to this, so I'm gonna keep the question up and see if someone has a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Max value telling by hard coding .]

I am suck in programming world. i m try help you..

Comment: Thx for the response, but as I stated in my question I already tried this, and it didn't really solve my problem.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. He does not want to limit it to a specific *number* of characters; he wants to limit it to whatever the physical size of the text box is.